# How to create const string from string variable

Tags: c#, string, constants

I want to create const string from another string variable. For example the next two code snippets can't compile

1)

```
string str = "111";
const string str2 = str;
```

2)

```
string str = "111";
const string str2 = new string(str.ToCharArray());
```

Which results in

```
Error: The expression being assigned to 'str2' must be constant
```

Is there any way to create a const string from string variable ?

Comment: Constant variable has to be fully known during the compilation, so it's not possible.

Comment: use readonly keyword instead of const

Comment: In these cases `static readonly` can help  substitute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short - no.

The value assigned to a `const` must be a compile time constant.

You can use `readonly` instead of `const`, which will let you change the value of the variable - you will only be able to change the reference in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Use *readonly* keyword.

```
string str = "111";
readonly string str2 = str.ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Because `const` variables are works on compile time.

Everybody agree on using `readonly`;

```
readonly string t = s + " World";
```

Answer (score 2):

Constants are evaluated at compile time so what you want is not possible. However you can substitute the constants with readonly, for example:

```
string s = "Hello";
readonly string t = s + " World";
```